# Upload fail with gapi php

Tags: javascript, php, google-api, token

I have this simple php code for upload a file:

```
require_once __DIR__."/../google_api/vendor/autoload.php";
use Google_Client;
use Google_Service_Drive;
use Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile;
session_start();

global $request; // the magic!
$request->enable_super_globals();

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig(__DIR__.'/../credentials.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE);

error_log(print_r("token: '" . $client->getAccessToken() . "'", true));

$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
$fileMetadata = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile(array("name" => "files/smallfile.txt"));
$file = $service->files->create(
  $fileMetadata,
  array(
  'data' => 
  file_get_contents("smallfile.txt"),
  'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
  'uploadType' => 'media'
   )
);
error_log(print_r("Id:". $file->getId(), true));
```

The library utilized is google apiclient 2.0 and the authorization seem to be ok but when i go to see the file on drive.google.com/drive/u/2/my-drive the file don't exists.

The printed error log are:

token:''

Id:1-6X90DaRPSxzc8xZynwubCVDmUdfLlWr

The token is not present and the id of file is displayed.

The idea is to take the token in backend with php and pass it to frontend for upload the file with javascript, but i don't view the token for do this.

someone can help me?

Thanks